# Acoustic Levitation Calculations

Tags: acoustics, frequency, estimation, levitation

I have recently started studying acoustic levitation and I would like to lift an object that is about 2.5 pounds. Surface area is about 5in x 5in. I am not very knowledgeable on the subject and I have had little success finding ways to calculate the decibel level, frequency, and amplitude necessary to accomplish this task. Any information would be helpful.